# Can "anscheinend" mean "apparently" in the surprised sense?

Tags: meaning

Besides stating something obvious, "apparently" can be used to indicate surprise:

> I just got my essay back. Apparently "diphthong" is spelt with "th".

Could it be translated with "anscheinend" in this case?

> Anscheinend wird "diphthong" mit "th" geschrieben.

Answer (score 7):

"Anscheinend" is correct.

"Offenbar" sounds slightly better here than "anscheinend". It emphasizes that the speaker thought differently before he got his essay back and is still a bit reluctant to accept that he was wrong.

Comment: Was about to post something similar, including *offenbar*, so +1. I'd add that you also see "Es scheint [[wohl] so [zu sein]], dass [...]" in situations like this.

Comment: "Anscheinend wird..." or "Überraschenderweise wird ..." are also common ways to express your opposing expectations. The latter would be the clearest adjective to state your surprise.

Comment: Regarding the emphasis that the speaker thought differently, I think it's quite the opposite: _offenbar_ implies _zweifellos_ (_obviously, without a doubt_), whereas _anscheinend_ means _allem Anschein nach_ (some doubt is left, the speaker is not 100% convinced).

Comment: @Hendrik Vogt: I'd attribute that to *offensichtlich* rather than *offenbar*. *Offenbar* is, at least in my experience, used similar to *anscheinend* and may also leave some doubt. The line may be blurry in colloquial use, of course...

Comment: @Hendrik: I disagree. "Offenbar", and more so "offensichtlich", can mean "obviously". But here it serves to slightly decline responsibility for correctness. The speaker expresses that his supposition is not based on his original thought, but that he has to take someone else's word for it.

Comment: @OregonGhost: You're right, _offensichtlich_ is stronger than _offenbar_. I'd place _offenbar_ somewhere between _anscheinend_ and _offensichtlich_.

Comment: You might also note that there is a bit of confusion about the meaning of the words `anscheinend` and `scheinbar`. These two are often used as synonyms, when in fact `anscheinend`means "apparently" and `scheinbar` only seems to be true, but in fact is not. Source: http://www.spiegel.de/kultur/zwiebelfisch/0,1518,315125,00.html

Comment: Offenschichtlich/offenbar wurde die Schreibweise von `Diphtong` durch den Eingriff des Zensors, daher ist sie nun offenbar(offensichtlich). Im Gegensatz transportiert `anscheinend` noch letzte Zweifel.

Comment: In Yiddish I think we would use "(es) weist aus" in this context. Is that used in German?

Comment: @Marty I haven't heard this before, if it's used at all it's either uncommon or a regional expression.

Comment: You'll find several examples of its usage in Yiddish groups like Mendele if you google it under the YIVO spelling "vayzt oys".